# .htaccess for Zend Debugger, Eclipse and Zend Framework

Tags: eclipse, debugging, zend-framework, mod-rewrite, zend-debugger

I want to debug my project in Zend Framework in Eclipse. Zend Debugger is already running bud now I have problem with Debug tool in Eclipse. It give an extra GET parametrs and the project in Zend don't like it.

I tried to google it and found [this](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFDEV/Configuring+Your+URL+Rewriter)

I modifed the *.htaccess* file but not make it working.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)?(start_debug=1.*)$ index.php?$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Don't know if its completely right because the Rewrite rules on the [page](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFDEV/Configuring+Your+URL+Rewriter) has some for me uknown flags which my Apache do not work with.

the link which is Eclipse making is

> http://localhost/?debug_start_url=http://localhost/&debug_session_id=1007&start_debug=1&debug_host=127.0.0.1&debug_no_cache=1229359621130&debug_port=10000&send_sess_end=1&original_url=http://localhost/&debug_stop=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with actual Zend Framework 1.9.6 and Zend Debugger it works without any special changes

Answer (score 1):

I successfully use the debugger and my htaccess looks like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (logs|library|application|config)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
</IfModule>
```

This basically says if the url doesn't lead to a directory that exists or a file then go through my index.php (also block out the logs, library, application and config folders because sometimes they are in the document root on some of my projects because of server limitations). Hasn't failed me on any project so far.